# How to create this HTML layout without the entire content overflowing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to have the following layout, where the right column will have a very long content and that should have a scrollbar for only the right column. However, every attempt I've made (as you can see I tried flex and grid but to no avail) makes the `.content` div outgrow the `.container` div which is not what I want.

How can I ensure that the scroll is only within the right side div and not the entire body?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: #222;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;*/
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 80vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  /*display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;*/
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.content > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.svg {
  background: green;
  height: 200rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="svg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-height:0 to .content